# Passing object to a Fragment via two activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my `FirstActivity`, user will log in. If the user exists in the database, it is loaded and should be "*passed*" to the `SecondActivityFragment` which is within the `SecondActivity`. The need is to check whether the user is with incomplete register, if so, the toolbar will display a warning menu item telling it to complete the registration.

```
┌FirstActivity
├─SecondActivity
└──SecondActivityFragment
```

Every tutorial that I see showing how pass data through Activity and Fragment talking about replace fragments and so on, I think that's not my case.

I created `newInstance()` on my `SecondActivityFragment` but I'm kinda lost.

```
public static SecondActivityFragment newInstance(User user) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("user", user);
        SecondActivityFragment fragment = new SecondActivityFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
}
```

And when user clicks in login button

```
if (userExists()) {
    userManager = new UserManager();
    User user = userManager.getByEmailPwd(editEmail.getText().toString(), editPwd.getText().toString());
    Intent secondActivity = new Intent(getContext(), SecondActivity.class);

    SecondActivityFragment.newInstance(user);
    startActivity(secondActivity);
}
```

Comment: This line isn't doing anything `SecondActivityFragment.newInstance(user);` You should pass an Intent with the User to SecondActivity, which in turn, gives it to the Fragment

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @TaylorCourtney sorry if I'm not made myself clear, but its how to pass user object to SecondActivityFragment.

Comment: @cricket_007 You say: pass to SecondActivity to pass to SecondActivityFragment?

Comment: Yes, the answer below is exactly what I'm saying

Comment: Just put second activity.putExtra() then in the second activity constructor onCreate get extras and search for that key.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll try @Vasily Kabunov answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put `user` into your `secondActivity` intent.

Then in the `SecondActivity`'s `onCreate` method get the `user` class using `getIntent().getSerializable()` and create an instance of `SecondActivityFragment`.

Comment: This was my first thought in the moment, but I wonder if exist some how to pass "directly". Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Calling

```
    SecondActivityFragment.newInstance(user);
```

that way, will not cause any effects in what will got presented.

If you want to present the fragment in the context of Second activity, consider passing the data that the fragment need to know to the Second activity - it should be sth like:

```
    secondActivity.putSerializable("user", user)
```

Then in SecondActivity's onCreate, or in other method, you have to replace fragment being displayed, for your SecondActivityFragment instance:

```
    User user = null;
    final Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(args.getSerializable("user") instanceof User){
        user = (User)args.getSerializable("user");
    }
    if(user != null){
        Fragment secondActivityFragment = SecondActivityFragment.newInstance(user);
        FragmentMenager fragmentMenager = getFragmentMenager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentMenager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_for_your_fragment, secondActivityFragment);
    }
```